# Creating a social network application

Tags: content-management-system, social-networking

I want to develop a social network application and I thought the CMS. So if you have an idea for a CMS tool that can do the trick thank you to guide me.

Answer (score 4):

IF you want to develop using ASP.net then

Take a look at  MonoX
Free ASP.NET CMS and Social Networking Platform
http://www.mono-software.com/Pages/MonoX-ASP.NET-Portal-Framework.aspx

Else

Take a look at Dolphin
http://www.boonex.com/dolphin/
open-source with free software package for building social networks,

End If

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You could use Joomla ([www.joomla.org](http://www.joomla.org)) together with a Community extension (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities). It's free, and runs on PHP + MySql

Answer (score 0):

Live Street CMS http://livestreetcms.com/ is pretty good